# Приложение открывает слишком много Mysql подключений одновременно

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, mysqli

Достался в наследство самописный проект.

При увеличении количества посещений, создается слишком много подключений к БД и это вешает другие сайты на Mysql сервере (их несколько).
Лимит подключений max_connections был ранее увеличен до 200 (дефолт 151)
так же ребята раньше логировали подключения, что наводит на мысли что проблема кроется именно здесь. В моменты пиковой нагрузки в логе создается до 200 новых подключений в минуту(код логирования подключений ниже).
Куски кода ответственные за подключение к БД:

```
private static $_connectionLink = null;
private static $_connectionErrors = null;

public function __construct() {
    if (empty(self::$_connectionLink)) {
        self::connect();
        $handle = fopen('connect.log','a');
        fputs($handle,"----------- NEW connect ".date('Y-m-d H:i')."----------- \n");
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
    private static function connect() {
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'user';
    $password = 'pass';
    $dbName = 'dbname';

    self::$_connectionLink = @mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbName);
    if (!mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        mysqli_set_charset(self::$_connectionLink, 'utf8');
    } else {

    }
}
```

Особое внимание к строке:`if (empty(self::$_connectionLink))` -

**Вопрос: корректно ли в данном случае проверять наличие уже открытого подключения с помощью empty()?**

Может быть здесь ошибка и в случае использования конструкции self::$_connectionLink 
empty() все равно возвращает TRUE даже когда переменная не пустая и тогда создается новое подключение даже если есть активное незакрытое?
Может быть надо делать что то вроде `if( null === self::$_connectionLink )` или `if (!self::$_connectionLink)`?
Или в чем еще может быть причина большого количества незакрытых подключений в данном случае?

Comment: Пробовали использовать префикс `p:` при указании хоста для открытия постоянного соединения?  http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: как много в коде проекта созданий экземпляра данного класса?
$db = new Your_Database_Class_Name();

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Их и должно быть много, если вы самостоятельно не выстраиваете очередь запросов со стороны приложения и не лимитируете количество соединений пулом, через которые оно работает. Здесь я так понимаю этого нет. Другое дело, что они должны моментально отрабатывать и вы их не должны видеть и нагрузку от них.

Лучше копать в сторону почему их в принципе много - почему раньше проект работал, а сейчас проблемы? Может страницы не кэшируются или кэш сломан, в результате приложение на каждый чих лезет в базу? Может база данных уже под нагрузкой и запросы стали втормаживать (причем все понемногу)? Запросы затормаживаются, дольше выполняются, дольше выполняются, дольше держат соединение, дольше держат соединение, меньше остается свободных соединений для обслуживания оставшихся запросов. В принципе MySQL по такому механизму и ложится – причем обычно не видно виновника, просто все запросы стали выполняться дольше и SHOW PROCESSLIST показывает те, которые выполняются чаще. Не получится бесконечно нагружать один сервер все новыми и новыми проектами. Может уже ресурсов сервера не хватает? Или сервер холодный?

PS Плюс удалите запись на диск при открытии соединения. Это лишнее ожидание при уже открытом соединении, если есть нагрузка на диск, вы так только увеличиваете время соединения с сервером MySQL, что еще больше усугубляет ситуацию. Если есть возможность, отправляйте лог-информацию на другой сервер при помощи syslog, пока ситуация не разрешится. При условии, конечно, что проект сам не дергает диск то и дело.

Comment: А если просто накинуть еще 50 - 100 к max_connections ? Это существенно отожрет память?

Comment: Лучше всего посчитать, сложите размер read_buffer_size + read_rnd_buffer_size + tmp_table_size + sort_buffer_size + thread_stack + join_buffer_size и умножте на 50. Это максимум который может потребоваться при самом неблагоприятном стечении обстоятельств (оценка сверху). Дело в том, что большинство эти буферов включаются лишь по мере надобности. Т.е. реально потребляться будет меньше, даже если будут задействованы все 50 потоков.

Answer (score 0):

1. Используйте постоянные соединения (префикс `p:` перед хостом `p:localhost`)
2. Открывайте соединение только тогда, когда оно реально нужно. Т.е. при отправке запроса на сервер.